# How do I align mixed-size divs within a container?

Tags: html, css

**Updated based on comments**

I'm trying to create div sections on a full sized page by making containers that are 30% of the width. Within those, I plan to have 2 or 3 div sizes aligned within them. I have a row with a large box that occupies 100% of the height, and a portion of the width, and then a box that's exactly half of the size. I'd like to have all of those half-size boxes be in the same row as the larger box  to create a nice stack. I'm assuming it's an issue of size vs position, but I haven't had much luck and I'm over-thinking the issue.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as9hud4k/10/

HTML:

```
<div class="content_section">
    <div class="content_thirdsize">
        <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_row">
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_large"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>

            <div class="content_thirdsize_inner_small"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content_thirdsize
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: rgba(83, 35, 128, 0.2);
}

.content_thirdsize_inner_row
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 105px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(83, 35, 128, 0.2);
    margin: 2px;
}

.content_thirdsize_inner_large
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(83, 35, 128, 0.2);
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    vertical-align: left;
}

.content_thirdsize_inner_small
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(83, 35, 128, 0.2);
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    vertical-align: right;
}
```

Comment: You can't reuse ID's on page, you need to make those classes instead.

Comment: Also, an image of what this is supposed to look like would be useful because I'm not grasping it from your description.

Comment: Sorry about that... this is what I hope to achieve

http://imgur.com/gallery/ysQECl1

Also, I'll change those to classes and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the math may need to be tweaked to account for spacing but `flexbox` can do a lot of the work here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
  background: orange;
}
.small-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 350px;
}
.large,
.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  border: 2px dotted white;
}
.small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="large"></div>
    <div class="small-wrap">
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div>
      <div class="small"></div </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PqQLpq)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much for your help on this. I'll be using that code as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using position and then align the divs using left, right, top, bottom. Pick a position setting that makes sense in your mind for moving the div and then fiddle with it's position until they line up as you would like.

As paulie_D said in the comments don't use IDs multiple times, they are supposed to be unique. You want to be using a class to apply the same style on multiple objects. My general rule is that classes are for applying style and IDs are for identifying a specific object on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll re-write it using that idea instead.

Comment: glad I can help; class vs. ID and positioning things on a page are, in my opinion, the two trickiest parts of CSS and HTML.

Comment: Agreed. Styling can get tricky especially when you're trying to stack elements like I am. The general layout of the page is fine, but it's those inner sections that are killing me.